# Query store audit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query-store

We frequently use query store force plan feature.
We would like to audit when and who forced each plan.
Is extended events session is needed auditing this event,
or there are dmvs or catalog views with this specific information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create some auditing on the execution of the `sys.sp_query_store_force_plan` procedure.

Create the server audit

```
USE master ;  
GO  
-- Create the server audit.   
CREATE SERVER AUDIT ServerAudit  
    TO FILE ( FILEPATH =   
'D:\AuditFiles\' ) ;   
GO  
-- Enable the server audit.   
ALTER SERVER AUDIT ServerAudit   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;
```

Create the database audit specification

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Audit_Plan_force
FOR SERVER AUDIT ServerAudit  
ADD (EXECUTE
     ON sys.sp_query_store_force_plan BY public)   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;   
GO
```

Force a plan in a user database

[image]

Query the audit file

```
SELECT   event_time,Action_id,succeeded,server_principal_name,database_name,object_name,Statement
FROM fn_get_audit_file('D:\AuditFiles\*',default,default);
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Probably will go for extended events session, any idea if in 2017 auto force plan if it will be the same